# getting Smoothed probabilities using linear interpolation for NLP model

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, probability

I have written a function which returns the Linear Interpolation smoothing of the `trigrams`

```
 def smoothed_trigram_probability(trigram):
        """
        Returns the smoothed trigram probability (using linear interpolation). 
        """
        assert len(trigram)==3, "Input should be 3 words"
        lambda1 = 1/3.0
        lambda2 = 1/3.0
        lambda3 = 1/3.0
        u,v,w = trigram[0],trigram[1],trigram[2]
        prob =  (lambda1* raw_unigram_probability(w))+\
        (lambda2* raw_bigram_probability((v,w)))+\
        (lambda3* raw_trigram_probability((u,v,w)))
        return prob
```

where the 3 methods `uni,bi, raw_trigram_probability` returns the raw probabilities as follows

```
 def raw_trigram_probability(trigram):
        """
        Returns the raw (unsmoothed) trigram probability
        """
        assert len(trigram)==3, "Input should be 3 words"
        return trigramcounts[trigram]/bigramcounts[trigram[:2]]


    def raw_bigram_probability(bigram):
        """
        Returns the raw (unsmoothed) bigram probability
        """
        assert len(bigram)==2, "Input should be 2 words"
        return bigramcounts[bigram]/unigramcounts[bigram[0]]


    def raw_unigram_probability(unigram):
        """
        Returns the raw (unsmoothed) unigram probability.
        """
        uni = []
        uni.append(unigram)
        assert len(uni)==1, "Input should be only 1 word"
        return unigramcounts[unigram]/total_words
```

In the above code, `uni,bi,trigramcounts` are the dictonaries which hold the information about the count of individual uni,bi and tri-gram counts in the document

I have used `total_words` in place of `unique_words` to calculate the probability of a unigram.

**Can some please tell me if this is the right approach beacause When I run the code with any unknown word, it throws `DivisionBYZeroError`**. This is obvious because count of a word can be 0 but is this usual?

**How can I write a method `sentence_logprob(sentence)`, which returns the log probability of an entire sequence using the `smoothed_trigram_probability` method?**

Comment: Has anyone generalized this to use and n-gram not just up to a tri-gram?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be something like this:

```
def getSentenceProbability(sentence):
# initialize probability to 0, used float to prevent double values from becoming 0
probability = float(0)

# split sentence into words
words = line.strip().split()

# create trigrams
trigrams = zip(*[words[i:] for i in range(n)])

for trigram in trigrams:
    probability += smoothed_trigram_probability(trigram)

return probability
```